# jquery 3.2.1 targetting elements by name is giving undefined even though they exist

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom, jquery-selectors

Is there anything glaringly obvious that I'm missing here:

I have the following markup in an application:

```
<table id="regulatoryInformationTable"> 

    <form id="searchRegulatoryInformation">
        <input type="hidden" name="id" value="ID000001"/>        
    </form>

</table>
```

Using jquery 3.2.1 I'm trying to get the value of the hidden field. I've tried:

```
$("#searchRegulatoryInformation input[name='id']").val();
```

and just

```
$("input[name='id']").val();
```

There are no other elements in the document with the ID `searchRegulatoryInformation` or the name attribute `id`.

I can't understand why, but when I `console.log()` either of these statements it's giving me `undefined`

**Edit** - it seems the issue (see comments) is the wrapping table `#regulatoryInformationTable`. If I remove this, I can target things by the ID `#searchRegulatoryInformation`. But with the table in place, I cannot.

Comment: Your code works fine in isolation: http://jsfiddle.net/xh8b2pcu/. Check the console for errors, and ensure there's only one element in the DOM with that `name` attribute and it exists at the point you run the JS.

Comment: the only reason I can think of is maybe the code is running before the element is created. Or maybe another error is crashing it before it gets to the relevant line. You haven't given us any context or made a runnable demo to reproduce it, so it's hard to be certain.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I've just made my own fiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/7xjvc8u3/) and it does seem to work fine there. I can't understand why it doesn't work in my application given there's nothing conflicting with it on the rest of the page.

Comment: I think you must have not implemented your code in $( document ).ready() block. http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/

Comment: @Andy in that case you need to compare and contrast your demo carefully with the real code. We can't do that for you, obviously. There must be some difference, probably along the lines Rory and I have discussed. Try using the JS debugger to step through the code, maybe it'll reveal a problem with the timing of execution, or another error etc.

Comment: I have added ready block to your fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/7xjvc8u3/1/ . Try it in your original code

Comment: If this code is in a script block which is earlier in the HTML than the actual form tag, and the code is not wrapped in a "ready" function (or otherwise triggered later on in the page lifecycle) then the browser will execute it before it renders the form tag and input, and therefore JS will not be able to detect the input element, because it has not been added to the DOM at that time. If you haven't got any console errors, than that seems by far the likeliest explanation. The other possibility, as Rory said, is multiple elements with the same name, and the code is selecting a different one.

Comment: If you still need our help, try to make a JSFiddle which represents an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so we can see the issue directly for ourselves. (And, maybe the process of constructing such a thing will actually reveal the problem to you, since you'll have to add things to your current example until it stops working).

Comment: There aren't any conflicting elements on the page, and the `<script>` block is further down than the markup. Everything is loaded on page load - not ajax etc - so the elements exist. I agree it must be something else within the page; unfortuantely I can't post the full markup as the content shown is in a private application. Thank you, I will carry on looking, I was checking I wasn't missing something obvious. The code is inside a ready function etc. It works on jsfiddle (with other parts of the markup removed of course) as you've all said, so I accept it'll be something in the markup.

Comment: Ok, I've managed to reproduce the issue here: http://jsfiddle.net/0c8xrqLg/ There is a table with an ID `#regulatoryInformationTable` and my form (`#searchRegulatoryInformation`) is inside it. It seems that I can't target the things inside `#searchRegulatoryInformation` unless I remove the table. @RoryMcCrossan @ADyson

Comment: The problem there is because the HTML is invalid. A `form` cannot be a child of a `table`. If you use correct HTML then the JS will work: http://jsfiddle.net/0c8xrqLg/1/ or http://jsfiddle.net/0c8xrqLg/2/

Comment: I wasn't aware of this. The context of the application is that I'm adding form inputs to column headings (inside `<thead> <th>` elements) to provide search functionality on specific columns of a table. Given that that's a very common scenario, I guess there's a workaround that involves the `<form>` tag wrapping the `<table>`?

Comment: Even with the invalid markup, input[name='id'] should still match your input. (The reason the other selector doesn't is because the input is being moved out of its parent form altogether.)

Comment: @Andy: Yes, that's generally how you would mark up a form that is presented as a table.

Comment: @Andy the only thing which can directly be a child of a table element is either a table row, or a tbody or thead. Otherwise, the browser has no idea where within the table you were trying to display the element (even a form tag can be visible, if you add CSS styles to it). If you want to place something validly within the table it must be within a th or td (and those of course must be within a tr). Anything else is invalid. A table must consist of rows and cells with content in. If content falls outside a cell, it's logically impossible to know where to place it in the table.